# how to disable ssl support for doamain in plesk onyx?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, plesk, plesk-onyx

My SSL certificate license has expired and I don't want to extend it.My control panel is plesk onyx and I just removed the ssl certificate but I can't uncheck the ssl/tsl support tick ( it is unclickable ) as [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000715254-How-to-enable-disable-SSL-TLS-support-for-a-domain-on-a-Plesk-server-) link I have to log in with server adminstrator premmisions for disable it . My account have all premissons and its role is owner but I can't disable it! can you help me ?! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you can disable SSL/TLS support under administrator but can not do it under Client.

Most possible cause is that "Hosting settings management" permission is disabled.
You can enable it at **Subscriptions > example.com > Customize > tick "Hosting settings management" > OK**

Or for service plan at **Service Plans> service plan name > Permissions > tick "Hosting settings management" > Update & Sync**